# HTML readonly text field valus is not visible

Tags: html

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Item Number</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="choice.number" value="123456" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is the "readonly" input field value not visible?

Comment: The value is visible.

Comment: Is the container itself visible?
Does `choice.number` have a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *should* be visible [(Bootstrap docs)](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-readonly). There's something else going on in your stylesheet.

Open the [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#How_to_open_the_devtools_in_your_browser) in your browser and inspect the element's (and its parents') style declarations. Maybe there's something like

```
[readonly] {
  color: white;
}
```

applied unknowlingly. Or the value is removed by the Angular controller. You can check that by using `console.log(input.value)` some time after the page load.